# Timestamp, stripping time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am looking to get a timestamp for now but have it only be the timestamp for the date (since I will be using this value to query, I need precision).

I thought that I had figured my way around it, but for some reason I am off by a month.

```
function dateToday() {
  now = new Date(Date.now());
  year = now.getFullYear();
  month = now.getMonth();
  day = now.getDate();
  today = `${year}.${month}.${day}`
  console.log(today);
  date = new Date(today)
  timestamp = date.getTime();
  return timestamp
}
```

It is currently `2019.3.15`, but the function is logging `2019.2.15`.

Comment: Read the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: @castis thanks, i knew that was the behavior too.. brain malfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single step using the `setHours` function:

```js
function dateToday() {
  return new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This sets the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero, and returns the numeric timestamp.  [The documentation is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Syntax).

Note that this is relative to the user's local time zone.

Answer (score 2):

[`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns a zero-based index of the month for the `Date`.

For your purposes, just add 1:

```
month = now.getMonth() + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript months start from 0 means January

so `now.getMonth() + 1` is what you need.